# how to show default image if user have no photo

Tags: php, row

example if user have no photo in our database then row show default photo
 how can i do this please help me
thanks

```
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

      echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>Photo</th><th>Teacher Detail</th></tr>";

if ($rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr><td align='center'>";
    echo "<img src=images/".$row['photo'] ." width='90' height='90'></a></td>";
    echo '<td valign="top">Teacher Name: ';
    echo $row['name'], '<br/>';
    echo 'Teacher No: ';
    echo $row['teacherno'], '<br/>';
    echo 'Father Name: ';
    echo $row['fathername'], '<br/>';
    echo '</td></tr>';

        }
} else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">No results found!</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>"
```

Comment: can u edit in to my code becz im confuse

Comment: i updated the answer for you please check.

Comment: Since you have updated your question, pick a solution below. Replace the image `echo` with one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>Photo</th><th>Teacher Detail</th></tr>";

if ($rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<tr><td align='center'>";
        if (isset($row['photo']) && !empty($row['photo'])) {
            echo "<img src='images/" . $row['photo'] . "' width='90' height='90'></a></td>";
        } else {
            echo "<img src='images/noimage.jpg' width ='90' height = '90'></a></td>";
        }
        echo '<td valign="top">Teacher Name: ';
        echo $row['name'], '<br/>';
        echo 'Teacher No: ';
        echo $row['teacherno'], '<br/>';
        echo 'Father Name: ';
        echo $row['fathername'], '<br/>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan = \"5\">No results found!</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
   if(isset($row['photo'] && $row['photo'])
   { 
       echo "<tr><td align='center'>";
       echo "<img src=images/".$row['photo'] ." width='90' height='90'></a></td>";
    }
   else
   {
     echo "<tr><td align='center'>";
    echo "<img src=images/Sample.jpg" width='90' height='90'></a></td>";
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: i have given the soltuion for what you have asked for..if you have more queries, put up a new question with your query..

Comment: You have not formed the question well, you asked for image, after implementing above code image will come up, but may be your other parameters are empty, so use `isset()` and `empty()` functions for name, tecaherno, father name just as i have done for `$row['photo']`..

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
echo "<img src=images/". $row['photo'] === NULL ? "default_img" : $row['photo'] .
"width='90' height='90'></a></td>";
```

Comment: not working dear 22.jpg width='90' height='90'> its showing like this on my page

Comment: Did you close the string? You actually should have `<img src='images/" and then at then end have "'width.." (i.e. you need the single quotes)

Comment: I can't because I'm a new user and I can't make edits < 6 characters

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($rows > 0){
     echo 'the user photo';
else{
     echo 'default photo';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be a complete section of the code at hand.

However, I would recommend removing the `die(mysql_error())` if your query is intact, and then   after the two echo statements try something like:

```
 } else {
    echo "<img src='images/default_image.png' width='90' height='90'>";
 }
```

Also of note is you have a terminating `</a>` without an opening `<a>` tag. This is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see if `$row['photo']` is not empty or contains a string. If we get a match, then the user has an image, otherwise, we can output the default image. A nice sample follows.

**The Code**

```
if (!empty($row['photo']) AND isset($row['photo'])){
    // Image is not empty and there is data contained within the array value
    echo "<img src='images/" . $row['photo'] . "' width='90' height='90' />";
} else {
    // There is no data contained within the value, show the default image
    echo "<img src='images/default_image.png' width='90' height='90' />";
}
```

**What's going on?**

using `empty()` we use this to determine if a string (or an array) is empty, if it is, this will return `FALSE`. `isset()` checks to see if the variable is set, if it isn't, it will return `FALSE`.

-- *snip* --
User changed question, answer changed.